# andengine move a sprite on given path

Tags: andengine

I want to move a rabbit on given path. then I have created a rabbit in right side and the carrot is and left right. I have given the path but that rabbit move auto, I used pathmodifer.

```
final AnimatedSprite stayrabit = new AnimatedSprite(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 90,32,32, this.mrabitTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) { 
    final Path path = new Path(10).to(CAMERA_WIDTH - 58, 90).to(10, 90);
}

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    //this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
    PathModifier pathModifier = new PathModifier(20, path);

    this.registerEntityModifier(pathModifier);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code on onAreaTouched method like this - 
@Override

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
   if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP)
   {
      MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(pDuration, your mouse x position, your carrot x position );
      this.registerEntityModifier(mod);
      return true;
   }
```

and register touch area of sprite to scene.